# How to sort recyclerview by lowest number / String Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sorting, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview in my app, that contains two textviews, one is rankTextView and other is nameTextview. Something like this;

[image]

What I want to do is sort this recyclerview, firstly in lowest number order and if there is two same numbers then I want it to be sorted out by Strings. In the above screenshot I have for example, two people rank 1, firstly I want the recyclerview to put these to the top and then sort it out by String.

I have searched online to see how can I go about doing this but being new to android I haven't been able to play around/adapt the findings into my project. For example;

[How to sort Strings on an Android RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419136/how-to-sort-strings-on-an-android-recyclerview)

[What is the SortedList<T> working with RecyclerView.Adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795299/what-is-the-sortedlistt-working-with-recyclerview-adapter)

I have created a custom adapter that contains a textview called rankTextview and another textview called nameTextview, like this;

```
 rankTextview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ranktextview);
 nameTextview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nametextview);
```

then I have a method that takes what value to put in these textview as parameter, like this;

```
 public addPerson(String rankTextview, String personTextview,) {
        this.rankTextview = rankTextview;
        this.personTextview = personTextview;
    }
```

and then I call this method in my main class to add data, like this;

```
person.add(new addPerson
        ("1\nrank", "James Kub"));
person.add(new addPerson
        ("2\nrank", "Peter Hanly"));
person.add(new addPerson
        ("3\nrank", "Josh Penny"));
person.add(new addPerson
        ("1\nrank", "Danny Jackson"));
person.add(new addPerson
        ("3\nrank", "Brad Black"));
```

Now what I want to do is sort out this data firstly by rank lowest number order e.g 1, 2,3... and if there are two same numbers then I want to sort out by name alphabetical order. Also, in future my app will contain points in stead of ranks which will be decimal numbers like this. 1.1, 1.5, 1.1, 2.1, 2.5 and so on, so would it possible to take in count decimal numbers when sorting out by rank.

Also, since I had so many lines of code, I wasn't sure which section to provide and which not to provide, please let me know if there is any code I am missing that I should have included.

EDITED:

```
public void animateTo(List<ExampleModel> models) {
        applyAndAnimateRemovals(models);
        applyAndAnimateAdditions(models);
        applyAndAnimateMovedItems(models);
    }

    private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(List<ExampleModel> newModels) {
        for (int i = mModels.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            final ExampleModel model = mModels.get(i);
            if (!newModels.contains(model)) {
                removeItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(List<ExampleModel> newModels) {
        for (int i = 0, count = newModels.size(); i < count; i++) {
            final ExampleModel model = newModels.get(i);
            if (!mModels.contains(model)) { // error here, saying cannot resolve method contains
                addItem(i, model);
            }
        }
    }

    private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(List<ExampleModel> newModels) {
        for (int toPosition = newModels.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
            final ExampleModel model = newModels.get(toPosition);
            final int fromPosition = mModels.indexOf(model);
            if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
                moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
            }
        }
    }

    public ExampleModel removeItem(int position) {
        final ExampleModel model = mModels.remove(position); // Error here, saying in sortedlist cannot be applied to (int)
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        return model;
    }

    public void addItem(int position, ExampleModel model) {
        mModels.add(position, model); // Error here, saying add has private access in 'android.support.v7.util.SortedList'
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        final ExampleModel model = mModels.remove(fromPosition); // Error here, saying in sortedlist cannot be applied to (int)
        mModels.add(toPosition, model); // Error here, saying add has private access in 'android.support.v7.util.SortedList'
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are some options for implementing sorting in a `RecyclerView`. Of course it is possible to rely on `Comparable<T>` and `Comparator<T>` interfaces but, as you mentioned, it is also possible to exploit `SortedList<T>` class defined in Android SDK.

Purpose of `SortedList<T>` is simplifying sorting of elements in a `RecyclerView`, allowing you to intercept significant events like "new item added", "item removed" and so on.

In your case you can proceed as follows:

1. Define a Person class for wrapping rank and name. Please notice that in this version I'm assuming to have integer values for rank, but it's quite easy to move to decimal value.

   ```
   class Person {

       private String rank;
       private String name;

       public Person(String rank, String name) {
           this.rank = rank;
           this.name = name;
       }

       // getters and setters here

   }
   ```
2. Define an Activity where to build `RecyclerView` and corresponding adapter. In this example I've included a `FloatingActionButton` for inserting new random Persons. As you can see, when creating a new `Person`, method `addPerson` is invoked on the adapter. Its effect will be to update the `RecyclerView`, sorting it according to criteria defined within the adapter itself (see point 3).

   ```
   public class SortPersonsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       private List<Person> mPersons;

       private SortPersonsAdapter mPersonsAdapter;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_persons_list);
           Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
           setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

           mPersons = new ArrayList<>();
           mPersons.add(new Person("1\nrank", "James Kub"));
           mPersons.add(new Person("2\nrank", "Peter Hanly"));
           mPersons.add(new Person("3\nrank", "Josh Penny"));
           mPersons.add(new Person("1\nrank", "Danny Jackson"));
           mPersons.add(new Person("3\nrank", "Brad Black"));

           RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lst_items);
           recyclerView.setLayoutManager(getLayoutManager());
           mPersonsAdapter = new SortPersonsAdapter(this, mPersons);
           recyclerView.setAdapter(mPersonsAdapter);

           FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
           fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   // building new fake person
                   Person person = new Person(
                           buildRandomInt(10) + "\nrank",
                           buildRandomName(5) + " " + buildRandomName(5));
                   // let's keep also basic list updated
                   mPersons.add(person);
                   // let's update adapter
                   mPersonsAdapter.addPerson(person);
               }
           });
       }

       private RecyclerView.LayoutManager getLayoutManager() {
           LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
           llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
           return llm;
       }

       // support method for random names and ranks here

   }
   ```
3. Implement a RecyclerView Adapter relying on `SortedList<Person>`. Here it's important to notice that all Persons are inserted into a `SortedList<Person>`. Creating a `SortedList<T>` requires a `Callback` to be defined for intercepting events as well as for defining sorting criteria. In our case, as you can see, `compare` method defines criteria for sorting Persons while `onInserted` method defines what to do when a new Person is inserted (notify a data set change for updating `RecyclerView` in this case). Please notice also implementation of `addPerson` method described at point 2. It just adds a Person to the `SortedList`, because the logic for updating `RecyclerView` is embedded into the `Callback` method `onInserted` mentioned before.

   ```
   class SortPersonsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SortPersonsAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

       protected static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

           View layout;
           TextView txt_rank;
           TextView txt_full_name;

           public PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
               super(itemView);
               layout = itemView;
               txt_rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_rank);
               txt_full_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_full_name);
           }

       }

       private Context mContext;
       private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

       private SortedList<Person> mPersons;

       public SortPersonsAdapter(Context context, List<Person> persons) {
           mContext = context;
           mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           mPersons = new SortedList<>(Person.class, new PersonListCallback());
           mPersons.addAll(persons);
       }

       public void addPerson(Person person) {
           mPersons.add(person);
       }

       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           return mPersons.size();
       }

       @Override
       public SortPersonsAdapter.PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
           View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_person_item, parent, false);
           return new PersonViewHolder(itemView);
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(final PersonViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
           Person person = mPersons.get(position);
           viewHolder.txt_rank.setText(person.getRank());
           viewHolder.txt_full_name.setText(person.getName());
       }

       /**
        * Implementation of callback for getting updates on person list changes.
        */
       private class PersonListCallback extends SortedList.Callback<Person> {

           @Override
           public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
               String[] rank1 = p1.getStringRank().split("\n");
               String[] rank2 = p2.getStringRank().split("\n");
               int diff = Integer.parseInt(rank1[0]) - Integer.parseInt(rank2[0]);
               return (diff == 0) ? p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName()) : diff;
           }

           @Override
           public void onInserted(int position, int count) {
               notifyItemInserted(position);
           }

           @Override
           public void onRemoved(int position, int count) {
               notifyItemRemoved(position);
           }

           @Override
           public void onMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
           }

           @Override
           public void onChanged(int position, int count) {
           }

           @Override
           public boolean areContentsTheSame(Person oldItem, Person newItem) {
               return false;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean areItemsTheSame(Person item1, Person item2) {
               return false;
           }

       }

   }
   ```

Hope this could help. [Here](https://github.com/thetonrifles/android-recycler-view/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/thetonrifles/recyclerviewsample/sort) I've put an implementation for your `RecyclerView`, in case you need more details on code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed answer.  On this line, 'private class PersonListCallback extends SortedList.Callback<Person>' it says, 'Class 'PersonListCallback' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'compare(T2,T2) in 'Callback''

Comment: Also, you see my getRank it a string because it contains the text 'Rank' and a number. You are calling getRank int diff, therefore its giving back an error. Any suggestion please.

Comment: @Henry Regarding rank it's probably better to use a number and append the "rank" suffix at UI level (check the app on repo, it's working in this way). This would make sorting much easier. Think about strings "1 rank", "2 rank" and "11 rank". If you sort them as strings you will have "2 rank" after "11 rank". This will not happen if you handle them as integer and add "rank" suffix just in UI.

Comment: @Henry Are you experiencing error with code taken from repository? I'm using it on my device and it's working fine. [This is what I see](http://i.imgur.com/mR8Zegd.png).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt reply. I was only taking code that I needed because I have already set up my setter and getters like shown in your example, however, my getRank is a string because it contains a number and letter.

Comment: @Henry Ok no problem. I was asking about repo just because I'm not experiencing errors on SortedList.Callback, so in case I need to know how you are using such class. Regarding rank ok... I think using integer is better, but if for you is mandatory to use a string I can modify code. Give me just few time.

Comment: @Henry I've updated answer code, handling rank as a String. In particular I've updated `compare` method implementation.

Comment: Hi, thanks after adding you aupdated code it doesn't give any error now. I am working on implementing rest of the code. I will let you know how I get a long, also if possible can you provide me with full project please. Thanks.

Comment: @Henry Sure. Full repository is [here](https://github.com/thetonrifles/android-recycler-view). It is an app implementing some examples of `RecyclerView` usage. The one under sort package is your same. I've just updated rank as String even there. When you launch the app you need to select button "Sorted List" for accessing.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I have a small problem, I have used this guide to implement a searchview with my recylerview https://github.com/Wrdlbrnft/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo and following this guide PersonsAdapter (SortPersonsAdapter) I have plain List instead of sortedlist and now when I try to change it to sortedlist, I get an error on (please see edited section of the post) saying that int cannot be used in sortedlist. Please help.

Comment: @Henry Well, if you need to use a `SearchView` for filtering items it would be better to implement sorting without `SortedList`. It is not so complicated. You need to make `Person` class to implement `Comparable` interface and then use `Collections.sort(mPersons)` over your list before notifying changes. If you need I can give you more details on it.

Comment: @Henry Now I see your edited post. `SortedList` is not a `List`, so it has a different interface. It is possible to exploit methods for adding and removing items but they can be different from the ones defined in `List`. I can try to check if possible to modify code for including this feature and keep `SortedList`.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Henry I've updated code for handling `SearchView` together with `SortedList` [here](https://github.com/thetonrifles/android-recycler-view/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/thetonrifles/recyclerviewsample/sort). It is possible to make some improvements, but everything depends on scenario where you want to use this approach.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to implement the sortedlist in the searchview on the guide because I have followed it step by step and linked it sucessfully with my recylerview. I am trying to change it according to the example you gave but I end up messing it up. If this is not possible is it possible to pass sortlisted to normal list and do the searchview handing then pass it back to sortedlist? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Henry I'm a little bit losing myself on outcome you are expecting. BTW I made a fork on repo you shared. If you want to apply sorting to items there, you just need `ExampleModel` class to implement `Comparable` interface and use `Collections.sort` method before initializing the adapter. Modified code is [here](https://github.com/thetonrifles/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo/tree/ec2c03825b89922eb48e9a4a0e1931eda5c65c57). I just edited `ExampleModel` and `MainFragment ` classes. In this way you will have sorting applied even while searching. Hope this could help.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and let you know. Sorry about being confusing.

Comment: @Henry ok no problem... I just hope at the end you'll be able to solve :)

Comment: I wish so to, I will let you knwo how I get along and I wish you could give more then 1 thumbs up so I could have given more to you for the time you have spent helping me :) thanks again!

Comment: Hi, this works to some extend however, in my app I have two textviews 1 containing ranks and other containing names, how can I add another function so that it also sorts it out by the names if two same numbers are found?

Comment: @Henry This is simple. In `compareTo` method within `ExampleModel` class you just need to bring logic for defining comparison criteria. Right now just sorting by titles is implemented. You can bring there the logic previously implemented in `compare` method of `SortedList.Callback` defined in my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101912/discussion-between-thetonrifles-and-henry).

Answer (score 8):

```
public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
   if(p1.getRank() == p2.getRank()){
      return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
   }else if(p1.getRank() > p2.getRank()){
      return 1;
   }else{
      return -1;
   }
}
```

The sorting depends upon what comparison result is returned. You need to return `-1`, `0`, or `1`. In the code snippet, all I am doing is checking the ranks first. If they are the same rank, I compare their names which are `String`s and every `String` has a `compareTo( )` which lexicographically compares two strings.

If not, we just sort them based on rank.

You can simplify your `compare( )` method further by making your `Person` class implement `Comparable` interface. That will allow you to use `Collections` framework goodies out of the box.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. So as this a method, when I call it in on create do I pass the customadapter class as parameter? also, since the rank textview is a string, because it contains a number and word, so I am getting an error, it says I can't use > on a String.

Comment: Also, thanks, I have given thumbs up when I get it to work I will mark it as correct.

Comment: "rank" should be a float. You want it to have decimals too. Storing this as a String is a bad idea.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the rank has to be a String because it contains a number and letters e.g. 1\nRank (1 Rank).

Comment: Also, when I call this method in onCreate, what value do I pass as parameter?

Comment: @Henry Rank should be a float. Make it a String later, in code.

Comment: Also, what do I pass as parameter when I call  the method? I can't seem to get it to work when I call my 'person' arraylist.

Comment: You don't have to call it on your own.

Comment: Sorry, I am little confused, how will be get in action if I don't call it.

Comment: Nope, no matter what I try, I can't seem to get it to work.